How one can show that this matrix is full rank?
Fix $d\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider $e_{i,j}\in\mathbb{C}$ for $i=1,\dots,d+3$ and $j=1,\dots,d-1$. Suppose to have the following matrices
$$N_{i,1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
e_{i,1} & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$N_{i,2}=\begin{pmatrix}
(-1)^de_{d-1} & (-1)^{d-1}e_{d-2} & \cdots & (-1)^2e_1 \\
0 & (-1)^de_{d-1} & \cdots & (-1)^3e_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A_{i}=\begin{pmatrix}
I_{d-1} & {^t}(N_{i,1}N_{i,2})
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B_{i}=\begin{pmatrix}
-N_{i,1}N_{i,2} & I_2
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$
S_i=\begin{pmatrix}
                    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & (-1)^d\\
                    (-1)^{d}e_{i,d-1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & e_{i,1}\\
                    0 & 0  & \cdots & (-1)^{d-1} & 0\\
                    (-1)^{d-1}e_{i,d-2} & 0 & \cdots & e_{i,1} & (-1)^d\\
                    \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
                    0 & (-1)^3 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
                    (-1)^3e_{i,2} & e_{i,1} & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
                    1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
                    2e_{i,1} & (-1)^3 & \dots & 0 & 0
                \end{pmatrix}$$
and consider the following matrix
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
A_1\otimes B_1 & S_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
A_2\otimes B_2 & 0 & S_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
A_{d+3}\otimes B_{d+3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & S_{d+3}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
I would like to prove that $M$ has full rank for the generic choice of the $e_{i,j}$'s (in particular it would be enough to prove it for a specific choice of the values). I know that the rank of the Kronecker product is the product of the rank of the matrices so that any $A_i\otimes B_i$ has full rank for the generic choice of the parameters, but I do not know how to say something about the rank of the whole matrix.
To be precise and honest, I can prove "by hand" that the whole matrix has full rank, for $d=3,4,5$, but the procedure is quite long and tedious, and it would be impossible to generalise it to the generic case. So, what I am looking for, is an argument more "intrinsic" and generalisable: I tried in many ways, but I couldn't find a smart way, could someone please help me? I would also appreciate a lot any kind of reference helpful for this problem.
Since the matrices $S_i$ are a little bit hard to understand, I write them here in the cases $d=3,4,5,6$.
If $d=3$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
-e_{i,2} & e_{1,1}\\
1 & 0  \\
2e_{1,1} & -1 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
If $d=4$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\
e_{i,3} & 0 & e_{i,1}\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
-e_{i,2} & e_{i,1} & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2e_{i,1} & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
If $d=5$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
-e_{i,4} & 0 & 0 & e_{i,1}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
e_{i,3} & 0 & e_{i,1} & -1\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
-e_{i,2} & e_{i,1} & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2e_{i,1} & -1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
If $d=6$ then
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
e_{i,5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & e_{i,1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
-e_{i,4} & 0 & 0 & e_{i,1} & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
e_{i,3} & 0 & e_{i,1} & -1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-e_{i,2} & e_{i,1} & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2e_{i,1} & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

The tedious work for these particular matrices can be delegated to a computer algebra system. What is the generic problem?

The generic problem is obtained considering not $e_{i,2},e_{i,3},e_{i,4}$ but $e_{i,j}$ for $j=2,\dots, d-1$ with the matrices changing as a consequence. And then you have to consider not just 8 blocks but $d+3$. Do you think that a computer algebra system could solve the problem for a generic d?

This does not seem clear, for $A_i$ and $B_i$, say $j=2$ , is $A_i=\begin{pmatrix}
-e_{i,2} & 0 & 1 & 0\
0&-e_{i,2} & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ ?
If yes maybe $B_i$ expressions follows but the expression of $S_i$ is not very symmetrical, please recheck, giving examples in lower dimensions ($j=2$ or $3$) also helps.

@ToniMhax I edited the text and now the problem is written in all its generality. If you could give me some suggestion, I would be very thankful

Ok I guess I saw the pattern, but that was guessing i'll try to get that. (You can as I said just write those matrices for small values $d =4,5,6..$ this helps the reader).

@ToniMhax done, I added them in the cased d=4,5,6, I hope now it is clearer, thank you!

This is long comment not provide an anwser to  your question
Let us  consider the structure of the block matrix $M$ and the properties of the Kronecker product. First, note that $B_i \otimes A_i$ has full rank 8 for generic choices of $(e_{i,2}, e_{i,3}, e_{i,4})$ because the rank of a Kronecker product is the product of the ranks of the individual matrices. Since each $A_i$ is a $2 \times 6$ matrix of rank 2 and each $B_i$ is a $4 \times 6$ matrix of rank 4, their Kronecker product $B_i \otimes A_i$ will have rank $2 \cdot 4 = 8$.
Now, consider the block matrix $M$:
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
B_1 \otimes A_1 & S_1 & 0_{8,4} & \cdots & 0_{8,4}\\
B_2 \otimes A_2 & 0_{8,4} & S_2 & \cdots & 0_{8,4}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
B_8 \otimes A_8 & 0_{8,4} & 0_{8,4} & \cdots & S_8\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
By the structure of $M$, each $S_i$ provides additional rows that are linearly independent of the rows in $B_i \otimes A_i$. Hence, the combined structure of $M$ ensures that the full rank condition propagates through the entire block matrix. Therefore, for a generic choice of the parameters $(e_{i,2}, e_{i,3}, e_{i,4})$, the matrix $M$ will indeed have full rank. This argument can be generalized to larger matrices with similar structures.

Some of your answer is a copy of the OP, did you have computer assistance in formulating this answer?
